# How to get box dimensions of canvas context?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm just getting into using the canvas element in HTML.

I've hit a snag where I am overlaying an image with paths. When someone clicks on the path, I can use the **isPointInPath** method to know which path has been clicked on.

The problem is that I want to redraw the image zoomed into the outer border of the path but I can't see a way to retrieve that information.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(can.width / 2, can.height / 2, can.height / 2.5, ((2 * Math.PI) / 10) * 7, (2 * Math.PI) / 10);
ctx.lineTo(can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
ctx.closePath();
```

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JohnSReid/78PEX/, I've drawn an arc. If I use the points that I've drawn like in the code above then I'll crop the outer points of the arc.

Is there a way to grab full the dimensions of the area that the arc is using?

Comment: As far as I know, you'll need to calculate it. It shouldn't be too hard. I would start with a bounding-box that encloses a circle of the same radius as the arc, before adjusting each of the 4 sides as required. Since the arc passes through both 0° and 90°, you can tell that you dont need to adjust the top or the right sides. You just need to calculate the coords of the endpoints since 180° and 270° aren't passed through, adjust the left and bottom, respectively. ('Conventional' angles used) - I forgot the canvas is 'upside-down', i.e 90° is down rather than up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9xgwY/

[image]

You can get any point on the circumference of a circle (or your arc) like this:

```
function XYonCircle(cx,cy,radius,radians){
    var x=cx+radius*Math.cos(radians);
    var y=cy+radius*Math.sin(radians);
    return({x:x,y:y});
}
```

To get the bounding-box of your arc:

```
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var PI2=Math.PI*2;

var left=XYonCircle(cw/2,ch/2,ch/2.5,PI2/10*7).x;
var top=XYonCircle(cw/2,ch/2,ch/2.5,PI2*.75).y;
var right=XYonCircle(cw/2,ch/2,ch/2.5,0).x;
var bottom=XYonCircle(cw/2,ch/2,ch/2.5,PI2/10).y;
```

If you change your arc, some bounding points will be at any of these angles that the arc passes through: 0,PI/2,PI & PI*3/2.

The remaining bounding points will be at the starting and ending of the arc.